# Паскаль. Расставить буквы в слове в алфавитном порядке

Tags: массивы, строки, pascal, freepascal

Есть слово на вход. Нужно сделать так, чтобы на выход программа переставляла буквы этого слова в алфавитном порядке и выводила полученное слово.
Т.е. если на вход было получено: "Стол", то программа должна вывести "Лост".

Через какие процедуры или функции можно выполнить данную задачу?

Comment: Привести все символы к нижнему регистру, отсортировать, изменить регистр первой буквы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем случае примерно так делается. Но по хорошему стоило бы строку для начала перевести в нижний или верхний регистр, потому как сравниваются коды символов, а у больших и малых букв они отличаются, следовательно перестановка может не адекватно работать

```
var
  str: string;
  i,j,n: integer;
  ch: char;
begin
  write('Введите слово: ');
  readln(str);
  n:=length(str);
  for i:=1 to n-1 do
    for j:=i+1 to n do
      if str[i]>str[j] then
      begin
        ch:=str[i];
        str[i]:=str[j];
        str[j]:=ch;
      end;
   writeln('Результат:');
   writeln(str);
   readln
end.
```

Поскольку вы не дали никакого кода, то подумайте сами над изменением регистра, сортировку я вам дал

Comment: Ваш код некорректно обработает букву "ё", т.к. при прямом сравнении, она идет по порядку после "я".

Comment: @Kromster бесспорно, но основной принцип думаю, человеку будет ясен и так, ту же 'ё', как и 'z' можно отдельно извернуться и обработать

Comment: Как пример - можно в самом начале пробежать по строке и все 'ё' заменить на 'е'

Comment: "и все 'ё' заменить на 'е' " - за такое точно побьют

Comment: @A.Hall можно их отдельно обрабатывать, каким образом - надо подумать правда

Comment: Решил вопрос с "ё" через цикл и if

Answer (score 0):

**PascalABC.NET**

```
begin
  var s := readString();
  var chars := s.toLower().toCharArray();
  chars.sort();
  chars[0] := chars[0].ToUpper();
  s := string.create(chars);
  writeln(s);
end.

// Input: Стол
// Output: Лост
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]